# compareAndSet on processors that does not support CAS operation

Tags: java, multithreading, compare-and-swap

Today I was asked the next question on an interview: "What is going on with compareAndSet method from AtomicLong in case you call it on a machine with a processor that does not support CAS operation".

Could you please help me with this question and provide some links to a comprehensive description if possible?

Answer (score 6):

From [Java Concurrency in Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601) **15.2.3 CAS support in the JVM** :

> On platforms supporting CAS, the runtime inlines them into the appropriate machine instruction(s); in the worst case,
>   if a CAS-like instruction is not available the JVM uses a spin lock.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the `AtomicLong` class source. We can find this:

```
/**
 * Records whether the underlying JVM supports lockless
 * compareAndSet for longs. While the intrinsic compareAndSetLong
 * method works in either case, some constructions should be
 * handled at Java level to avoid locking user-visible locks.
 */
static final boolean VM_SUPPORTS_LONG_CAS = VMSupportsCS8();
```

It means it will work in eatiher case. Depending on the implementation JVM may try to acquire lock and if it could not try again (polling).

Judging by the comment, JVM uses [`std::atomic::compare_and_exchange_strong`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange_strong/).

```
/**
 * ...
 * <p>This operation has memory semantics of a {@code volatile} read
 * and write.  Corresponds to C11 atomic_compare_exchange_strong.
 * ...
 */
@ForceInline
public final boolean compareAndSwapInt(Object o, long offset,
                                       int expected,
                                       int x) {
    return theInternalUnsafe.compareAndSetInt(o, offset, expected, x);
}
```

Comment: First of all thank you very much for your response. But I am interested in an exact difference of behaviour for processors that support CAS and processors that do not. It seems that in case of processors that do not support CAS, there is some other sort of synchronisation is done for compareAndSet methods. I need a little bit more details.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know about the exact difference except periodic polling some mutex by JVM for being locked :). It's not specified and may vary from JVM to JVM. Maybe C11 method `std::atomic::compare_and_exchange_strong` on Non-CAS processor working principle will help.